# Iniciando em POO (PHP) e tenho a seguinte dúvida;

Tags: php, mysql, orientação-a-objetos

Há um bom tempo que estou a buscar informações para desvendar os mistérios de POO (PHP) e não as encontro.

Gostaria de saber como faço para chamar determinada função em outro arquivo através da execução de um formulário, exemplo;

**<<login.php>>**

```
 <form name="login" method="post" action="funcoes.php">
        <h1>Acesso</h1>
        <p>Nick
           <input type="text" id="user" placeholder="Insira o nome de usuario" name="user"></p>
        <p>Senha
          <input type="password" id="senha" placeholder="Insira a senha" name="senha"></p>
        <p class="lead">
          <button type="submit">Entrar</button>
        </p>
      </main>
    </form>
```

**<<funcoes.php>>**

```
 <?php
         class conta{
        
                function autenticacao(){
                    $user=htmlspecialchars($_POST["user"]);
                    $senha=htmlspecialchars($_POST["senha"]);
                    $sql="select * from operador where usuarioOp='$user'";
              
                    $resultado=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
                    $fim=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
              
                    if($senha=$resultado){
                        echo"log_ok";
                        $_SESSION['id']=$fim['idOp'];
                        $_SESSION['nick']=$fim['usuarioOp'];
                        $_SESSION['nome']=$fim['nomeOp'];
                        $_SESSION['rank']=$fim['rankOp'];
                      
 
 $_SESSION['nick']=md5('seg'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
                        
                        header('location:login.php');
                        }else { 
                        echo"log_erro";
                        session_unset();
                        header('location:index.php');
                      }
                }
        
                function cadastro(){
                    $user=htmlspecialchars($_POST["user"]);
                    $senha=htmlspecialchars($_POST["senha"]);
                    $nome=htmlspecialchars($_POST["nome"]);
                    $nasc=htmlspecialchars($_POST["nascimento"]);
                    $cpf=htmlspecialchars($_POST["cpf"]);
                    $rank=htmlspecialchars($_POST["rank"]);
                    $result=mysqli_query($link,"insert into operador (usuarioOp, senhaOp, cpfOp, nomeOp, nascimentoOp, rankOp) values ('$user', '$senha', '$cpf', '$nome', '$nasc', '$rank' )")or die (mysqli_error());
                        if($result){
                            $_SESSION["nome"]=$nome;
                            $_SESSION["user"]=$user;
                            echo "cad_ok";
                            header("Location:online.php");
                            
                        }else {
                              echo "cad_erro";
                              header("Location:login.php")
                              }
                }
            }
        ?>
```

Fiz apenas isso e não encontro nada referente a minha dúvida na internet, gostaria de usar apenas o PHP para chamar a função *autenticacao* no arquivo *funcoes.php* através da requisição do submit no formulário em *login.php*. antes eu estava a usar IF e etc, mas decidi por tentar descobrir novos métodos para agilizar os procedimentos.. pois ficar fazendo if para cada função fica difícil... muita função similar com recolhimento de dados diferentes.

Agradeço quem puder me ajudar. E espero que isso venha a sanar algumas dúvidas alheias futuramente, caso seja solucionado. Grande abraço.

Comment: É interessante ter em mente que somente por utilizar uma classe não significa que está utilizando o paradigma POO. O paradigma tem princípios que devem ser seguidos, tais como, mas não limitados a, abstração e herança. Sem isso, você apenas criou uma classe para substituir algo que poderia ser funções. Aliás, da forma que está estruturando o código, faria mais sentido usar o paradigma procedural, com funções, do que se arriscar no POO.

Comment: Olá meu amigo, com certeza, não soube me colocar sobre, é que eu imaginei que a maioria que soubesse de POO (PHP) responderia essa questão com uma facilidade... rs Na realidade desejava executar funções mesmo, porém não obtive sucesso. Se puder/souber métodos de me ajudar, estou a buscar há um bom tempo na internet maneiras de fazer isso, li e reli a documentação do PHP e não consegui fazê-lo. Abraço.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar `(new conta())->autenticacao()` no final da declaração da classe.
Pra evitar ifs você pode criar mais arquivos, por exemplo `autenticacao.php` contendo:

```
require_once 'func.php';
(new conta())->autenticacao();
```

E outro chamado `cadastro.php`:

```
require_once 'func.php';
(new conta())->cadastro();
```

A action do form fica:

```
<form name="login" method="post" action="autenticacao.php">
```

Ainda assim, tente utilizar algum framework (laravel, symfony, etc) para padronizar seu código.

Comment: Olá! Obrigado pela ajuda! Fiquei em dúvida sobre como vou chamar exatamente a função, já que fica todas as variáveis por fora da classe, né? Daí quando eu chamo dá erro nas variáveis vazias, e a tela acaba por ficar em branco...